# Stop background shifting when switching between pages with/without scrollbars?

Tags: html, css

I have a static page that has no scroll bar. It links to another page that has a scroll bar. Both pages share the same background image. When I switch back and forth, I can notice the background image and page content shift slightly to the left due to the scrollbar being displayed on one page and not on the other.

I fixed this by doing [this trick](https://aykevl.nl/2014/09/fix-jumping-scrollbar), but it only works for the body content. The background image still shifts. Is there anyway to fix this? I have one fix ( overflow-y:scroll; ), which is always displaying the scrollbar, even when there is nothing to scroll, but it's not ideal.

My BG image code is:

> body {
>     background: url(img.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
>    -webkit-background-size: cover;
>    -moz-background-size: cover;
>    -o-background-size: cover;
>    background-size: cover;
>   }

Comment: As of today I have — not — heard of any other than always setting the scroll-bar.

Comment: You can use this plugin: http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First disable body scrolling. you can have background there:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: url('img.png') no-repeat center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

create a wrapper inside body like this:

```
<body>
   <div class="body">
     PAGE CONTENT
   </div>
</body>
```

now style that wrapper like this:

```
.body {
    height: 100vh; 
    overflow: auto;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Now you see the background does not change with or without scroll.

Comment: this works, in the sense it stops the bg image shifting, but the scrollbar position is messed up, and the body content now shifts around - https://i.imgur.com/XyKdrfQ.png

Comment: @noobman That is because you didn't reset the `body`. see my answer again for `margin` and `padding` of the body. In case you want padding for `.body` I added padding there.

Comment: looks perfect, thank you! but now the content still shifts around and the original fix i shared in the link doesnt work with it.

Comment: @noobman are you still using those fix on `html` tag? after using the wrapper, your main tag will be `.body`, not `html` or `body`.